# How to change copied value before paste in different sheet in excel by Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

Can you help me with this problem. I have the following code and i want to change copied value after "Selection.Copy" before "ActiveSheet.Paste"
For example: value before copy is "25_something". The value has to be "something" before "ActiveSheet.Paste", so that in cell D4 to put only something.

```
Sheets("All Sub Tasks").Select
    Range("D" & CStr(StartPos)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(SheetName).Select
    Range("D4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suggest to use a variable to hold and modify the value of the source cell, then after modification place that value in your target cell (see code below)
Suggest also to declare the workbook as well.
No need to select the worksheet as you are working now with objects and variables

```
Dim WbkTrg As Workbook
Dim CllValue As Variant

Rem Assuming target workbook is active
Set WbkTrg = ActiveWorkbook

CllValue = WbkTrg.Sheets("All Sub Tasks").Range("D" & CStr(StartPos)).Value2
Sheets(SheetName).Range("D4").Value = CllValue
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found solution for the problem. I put this row between "Selection.Copy" and "Sheets(SheetName).Select": Selection.Value = Mid(Selection.Value, InStr(1, Selection.Value, "_") + 1)